# Creating methods with class_eval

Tags: ruby, methods, metaprogramming, class-eval

I want to write a method which takes one parameter and creates another method, named with this parameter. Here is my code

```
class Class
  def createMethod(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    class_eval %Q{
        def #{attr_name}
            puts "bar"
        end
    }
  end
end

p Class.new.createMethod("foo").respond_to?(:foo)
```

Unfortunately, `respond_to?(:foo)` evaluates to `false`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `class_eval` is a class method and you're calling it in the context of an instance. You can do this instead:

```
class Class
  def createMethod(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    self.class.class_eval %Q{
        def #{attr_name}
            puts "bar"
        end
    }
    self # Return yourself if you want to allow chaining methods
  end
end
```

Here's the output from `irb` when doing this:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Class
irb(main):002:1>   def createMethod(attr_name)
irb(main):003:2>     attr_name = attr_name.to_s
irb(main):004:2>     self.class.class_eval %Q{
irb(main):005:2"         def #{attr_name}
irb(main):006:2"             puts "bar"
irb(main):007:2"         end
irb(main):008:2"     }
irb(main):009:2>   end
irb(main):010:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):011:0> clazz = Class.new
=> #<Class:0x007fd86495cd58>
irb(main):012:0> clazz.respond_to?(:foo)
=> false
irb(main):013:0> clazz.createMethod("foo")
=> nil
irb(main):014:0> clazz.respond_to?(:foo)
=> true
```

Comment: The reason it's still false is that your `createMethod` call returns `nil`, not the instance, so you can't chain the `respond_to?` call. You could put `self` right before the `end` of `createMethod` and that would work.

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parseable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Will do. Fixed.